# Retag request: [javscript] -> [javascript]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed today the [javscript](/questions/tagged/javscript) tag with about 24 questions applied to it.

Can these be retagged to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) please?

Comment: `[javscript]` now redirects to `[javascript]`, so I think you're all set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't argue with that. This should now be done, with a merge and synonym.